# У меня ошибка с HIBERNATOом: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Вот ссылка на англойязычную версию. Не могли бы Вы мне помочь, потому что советы на ссылочной версии  не помогли:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626399/error-with-hibernateunable-to-create-requested-service-org-hibernate-engine-jd][1]

Comment: Я уже кажется [отвечал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862623/204920)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что я не инициализировал контекст:

Для примера в main:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
MyService myService = (MyService) context.getBean("myService");
```

В этом сервесе подтягивались основные бины